# Unity3D-2D: Setting Time.timeScale to 0 for a certain public prefab until positioned?

Tags: c#, unity

So I have a button in my game which spawns a "tower" at a given location. The tower, when spawned, acts normally and I can drag it around using my drag script.

I wonder how can I set the Time.timeScale to 0 when I first spawn the tower (*only* for that prefab) UNTILL I click again to set it's position.

Comment: Did you try by removing `[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider2D))]` and added `BoxCollider2D` manually?

Comment: Please limit your question posts to a _single_ question. If you have more than one question, create another question post.

Comment: Sorry Alexandre, I didn't quite think before posting it. Thanks for editing!

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder how can I set the Time.timeScale to 0 when I first spawn the
>   tower (only for that prefab) UNTILL I click again to set it's
>   position.

You can't, because Time.timeScale is a static variable, so it's globally accessible and not set per-instance. However, stopping time is probably not necessary for what you want to accomplish anyway. Here are two better ways to do what you want:

1. Instantiate a TowerPlaceholder prefab instead of a Tower. A TowerPlaceholder "looks" like a Tower, but does not have the same logic and so does not need to be paused while spawning.
2. Add a flag to Tower that specifies whether it has "spawned" or not yet, and use that to control what updates are applied per frame:

   ```
   public class Tower : MonoBehaviour
   {
       bool has_spawned;

       ...
       // called once an object is placed in the world
       public void Spawn()
       {
           has_spawned = true;
       }

       void Update()
       {
           if(has_spawned)
           {
               // whatever your tower does normally
           }
           else
           {
              // whatever your tower should do when it's being dragged into position
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I really like the 2nd idea! I will try right now!

Answer (score 0):

At start you could disable its Rigidbody component or the script that is moving the tower. Then re-enable it when ever you want.

Comment: I'll try in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Set the behaviors that you want delayed as disabled in the source object. It will spawn (on first click) with logic in place, but not running. Then, when you click the second time to "plop" it, enable the script. This doesn't require polling within `Update()` and is event-like (especially when combined with `EventTrigger` components).

```
class Tower
{
  void OnPlop() //Preferably called by an EventTrigger
  {
    GetComponent<DraggableObjectBehavior>().enabled = false; //Disallow further dragging
    GetComponent<ActiveTowerBehavior>().enabled = true; //Enable "tower logic"
  }
}
```